# Can't push to master because of conflicts that aren't actually there

Tags: git, model-view-controller, azure-devops, repository

So i'm having a problem atm using Azure devops, i have a repository with master and 3 branches, Yesteday i pushed brand A into master and it worked perfectly and master now contains what was in branch A. However today i wanted to push branch B into master, but it says there are 16 conflicts. When i go into the files and compare side by side what the conflicts are, it looks like the conflicts that it says it has arent actually in the master let me give an example.

Master started out with a standard MVC project, that contained the standard MVC template (Index,contact,about html). When i pushed branch A into master yesteday those 3 HTML pages are now replaced with branch A's pages which is fine. BUT in the conflict page when merging Branch B with Master, it shows that there are conflicts between Master and Branch B because Master has (Index,About,Contact) in both the views folder and in the various codes throughout the project, However there's NO traces of any of that in the actual repository.

I can provide some pictures if needed.

Comment: You shouldn't try to push a branch on top of another. You need to merge changes from one branch to another, or rebase onto another branch. To me it sounds like you're not really familiar with the basics of Git so I would strongly suggest you do some reading up on how Git works and branching strategies.

Comment: You'd better share the screenshots about `it has arent actually in the master let me give an example` and `However there's NO traces of any of that in the actual repository`. Little confusing about this expression:-)

Comment: How are you pushing a branch into another? Do you mean merge?